# Can't generate table from Oracle Designer 6i

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, designer

a little background, I really don't know any technical terms from Oracle. My company have a pre built machine and I'm trying not having to go there backup my files and lose a day of job because I cant.

Recently I'm learning how to use Oracle Designer (6i) to build a diagram and later a table so I can request it to be created... While using the software it requested to install some file for the repository... after doing it, It screwed up every Oracle product I was using... I couldn't connect to PLSQL or even the designer...

After fixing some registry to point to the right TNSNAME and manually adjusting PLSQL, I managed to access both. The problem in hand is in oracle Designer at the "Designer Editor", when I right click a table and select generate, the message bellow shows up

```
Message
-------
CDD-23564: The file "C:\ORACLE\DSG6I\BIN\cds61.dll" could not be loaded or does not exist.  

Cause
-----
The specified file or one its dependent files could not be loaded.
This may be because a file has not been installed, or is not
correctly defined in the system registry.
As an example dependency, the Forms Generator files require the
Form Builder files installed as part of Developer.


Action
------
Check the registry settings for the location of the required
file. Also check the product and any required dependencies
e.g.Developer have been installed correctly.
If necessary, try reinstalling.
```

---

The dll mentioned IS and EXISTS on the mentioned folder. 
Considering I don't have the Oracle Developer 6i intaller, what can I do? What registry entry should I update?

Answer (score 1):

Designer 6 is long out of support.  Oracle has a free tool, [SQL Developer Data Model](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/overview/index.html), which does not break.

Even Designer 9i was flaky and would crash at random intervals and poke along with larger schemas.  Anything over hundred tables could take days to edit.  Ah, good times...

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the problem by copying and replacing the whole ORACLE_HOME\DSG6I folder (in my case c:\Oracle\DSG6I, for those confused in terms like me) and the oracle system registry (regedit > HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Oracle) from a coworker machine!